# Jmeter - sample collection mode (in distributed testing) doesn't switch to statistical, ignoring command line params

Tags: configuration, jmeter, load-testing, distributed, test-results

The situation is pretty much described in the question's header :)
Some details: Jmeter v 3.0 r1743807;
7 load generators in total, two windows servers, five redhat hosts. All machines in the same subnet. One windows server is used both as a jmeter-server, and a load controller at the same time. Testing REST-api systems, with loads of about 20-40k virtual users, performing a complex scenario. Everything seems to work pretty much OK, but I can't deal with the issue mentioned above - file with test results stores full requests and responses, which is not acceptable, because this data eliminate free HDD space at no time, and the further data can not be stored, which is very bad for analysing test results. For load tests I use non-gui mode, of course. Here is the command line:

```
C:\....\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\jmeter.bat -n -t C:\1\load_jmx\xxxx.jmx 
-l C:\1\....\YYY.jtl -R172.16.2zz.***,10.127.***.***,10.127.***.***,10.127.***.***,10.127.***.***,
172.16.xxx.4,127.0.0.1 -Gmode=statistical
```

Maybe the command lina arguments are overrided by some configs? When dealing with several jmeter issues I probably modified my config files not very responsibly. Thank you in advance for your help, colleagues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should rather add `mode=Statistical` line to *user.properties* file of each JMeter Slave engine as the property needs to be initialised during JMeter Engine bootstrap rather than coming from the master.

Alternative option is passing the property via [-J command-line argument](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like:

```
java -jar ApacheJMeter.jar -Jmode=Statistical -Dserver_port=1099 -s -j jmeter-server.log
```

References:

- [Using a different sample sender](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#sendermode)
- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)